# Ancestors path to be reformat for hierarchy nodes object

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I had reformat my data in mongodb using ancestors path to ensure the relationship of each nodes & intend to show it in a organisation tree view.

```
[
{
    "isActive": true,
    "ancestorsPath": [],
    "studentGroup": [
        "t2-001",
        "t2-002",
        "t2-003"
    ],
    "_id": "33d9704f34901855c911e433",
    "email": "user5@test.com",
    "agentId": "t1-001"
},
{
    "isActive": true,
    "ancestorsPath": [],
    "studentGroup": [
        "t2-101",
        "t2-102",
        "t2-103"
    ],
    "_id": "5cdb0664c409e90e4fe21133",
    "email": "user5@test.com",
    "agentId": "t1-100",
},
{
    "isActive": true,
    "ancestorsPath": [
        "t1-001"
    ],
    "studentGroup": [
        "t3-001",
        "t3-002",
        "t3-003"
    ],
    "_id": "5cdb06dec409e90e4fe21134",
    "email": "user5@test.com",
    "agentId": "t2-001",
}
]
```

However the data in organisation tree is using a format as below:

```
id: "T1-001",
    name: "user5@test.com",
    title: "general manager",
    children: [
      {
        id: "t2-001",
        name: "Bo Miao",
        title: "department manager",
        number: "MYR 2,000"
      },
      {
        id: "t2-002",
        name: "Su Miao",
        title: "department manager",
        children: [
          { id: "t3-001", name: "Tie Hua", title: "senior engineer" },
          {
            id: "t3-002",
            name: "Hei Hei",
            title: "senior engineer",
            children: [
              { id: "6", name: "Pang Pang", title: "engineer" },
              { id: "7", name: "Xiang Xiang", title: "UE engineer" }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      { id: "t2-003", name: "Hong Miao", title: "department manager" }
```

How should I format my data? Can anyone give me some pointers so i can study further?

Comment: Is there some correlation ?  Could you update the post to provide  more explanation as how the input tied to output ?

Comment: Yes, i need to use this input from an API to output on an organisation chart that uses a hierachy structure.

The data is having ancestors path (showing the ID's connected)
& children id (student's ID)

Comment: In case you need to simply traverse JSON, made random iterator for another question here https://github.com/eltomjan/ETEhomeTools/blob/master/HTM_HTA/JSON_Iterator_IIFE.js (answer with predefined iterators demo here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56698728/how-to-traverse-json-object-random-direction/56698756#56698756